# Twitter Bootstrap row divs don't work

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, row

I'm trying to make two columns on my site using Twitter Bootstrap, dividing the row div class as in the code below.

The problem is that syntax doesn't seem to work the same on my computer than on documentation sites. For example, if I copy the very source of an [example page](http://www.zetiz.com/sitepoint/#) it will appear whole differently, pools, and active menu items not appearing correctly, and colums being put under each other as paragraphs.

I couldn't find any clue with webkit inspector either, the code and file structure and encoding is the same as of the tutorial example site.

Any ideas someone?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title comes here</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span4">
                <p>Dummy Text</p>
             </div>

             <div class="span8">
                <p>Dummy Text</p>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just being cascaded as it's expected too, due to a smaller screen size?

Comment: You're code [looks fine to me in this example](http://jsbin.com/afeSUGeC/1/edit).  It's possible you're copying the code from a documentation site using Bootstrap 2 but have actually downloaded Bootstrap 3 yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a newer version of Bootstrap (3.X). The one used on your example is 2.3.2. The grid system is completely rebuilt for a better support of responsiveness.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

Instead of spanX, you should use col-xs-X, col-sm-X or col-md-X or col-lg-X
with X the number of columns.
xs,sm,md and lg depends of the size of the screen you want to support.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a different class to your column:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <p>Dummy text</p>
</div>
```

Choose the `md` part depending on the device size that code supports (`md` is medium, use also `lg` for large desktops, `sm` for tablets `xs` and smart phones)

- http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic
- http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

This applies to Bootstrap version v3.0.3

Comment: It looks like he is using Bootstrap version 2.3.2 so this wouldn't help.